# Check if string taken with Scanner.next() contains number

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I wanted to take a String using Scanner.next() and see if it contains a number or not. I used regex to check if a string contains anything but a number. The regex works correctly if the string is hard coded, but not when taken from keyboard. I expected input of 5 to be detected as a number, but it is not. Please tell me why. My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Error {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        String input = "";
        boolean isStringNumber = true;

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter a number only...");
        input = inp.nextLine();

        isStringNumber = input.contains("[^0-9]+");

        if (isStringNumber == false) {
            System.out.println("\nYou entered a non number " + input);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What would be the result of `foo5`? True or false.

Comment: any reason you're not using [Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())? It will return true if the line can be interpreted as an integer value. If you're trying to test whether or not the line simply contains a number (and could be other text as well), then one of the other answers should work.

Comment: nextInt for integers and nextLine for strings. not pointing you @RyanJ

Comment: Read the comment again. That's not what I said.

Comment: @RyanJ - I will not use nextInt because i want to check if the user enters an exit string. Hence, take string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) uses a `String` literal as its argument. Use `matches` instead

```
isStringNumber = input.matches("[0-9]+");
```

or simply

```
isStringNumber = input.matches("\\d+");
```

BTW: `Scanner` has a `nextInt` method for accepting integer values

Comment: I will not use nextInt because i want to check if the user enters an exit string. Hence, take string only.

Comment: Ok, so `contains` considers its input as just a string and not regex pattern. got it.

Answer (score 0):

instead    `isStringNumber = input.contains("[^0-9]+");`

try   `isStringNumber = input.matches("[0-9]+");`